# Three.js how to explode mesh with rectangles

Tags: javascript, three.js

We are trying to use the tessallation and explode modifier in this example (http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_modifier_tessellation) to explode a sphere into rectangles and not triangles.

Here is the link to the code we have    https://jsfiddle.net/cloacker/2dxp3ga8/

Displacement for the faces is calculated in this block of code. I believe this is calculated for three faces, but how to define adjacent faces or if that is even possible?

```
for ( var f = 0; f < numFaces; f ++ ) {
    var index = 9 * f;
    var h = 0.2 * Math.random();
    var s = 0.5 + 0.5 * Math.random();
    var l = 0.5 + 0.5 * Math.random();

    color.setHSL( h, s, l );

    var d = 10 * ( 0.5 - Math.random() );

    for ( var i = 0; i < 3; i ++ ) {
        colors[ index + ( 3 * i )     ] = color.r;
        colors[ index + ( 3 * i ) + 1 ] = color.g;
        colors[ index + ( 3 * i ) + 2 ] = color.b;

        displacement[ index + ( 3 * i )     ] = d;
        displacement[ index + ( 3 * i ) + 1 ] = d;
        displacement[ index + ( 3 * i ) + 2 ] = d;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I had to change the code to work with numFaces/4 to make it work for my sphere parameters.

Comment: you need to compute the index for each rectangle - triangle pair. For `numFaces`, you would assign `numFaces/2` instead of just `numFaces` of these random colors, and random displacement.

Comment: Thanks, your information got me looking in the right direction, I had to use numFaces/4 to get the rectangle - triangle pairs, because of the sphere parameters I use.